# How to remove empty rows from an md-virtual-repeat-container?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

The below code is working for me to get data on API calls but I have one question here. Every time it creates elements in DOM and populate the data which we get from API. But if I get lesser records it is showing blank/empty records. How can I remove or stop generating those blank records?

```
this.infiniteItems = {
    numLoaded_: 0,
    toLoad_: 0,
    items: [],
    getItemAtIndex: function (index) {
    if (index > this.numLoaded_) {
        this.fetchMoreItems_(index);
            return null;
        }
        return this.items[index];
     },
     getLength: function() {
        return this.numLoaded_ + 25;
     },
     fetchMoreItems_: function (index) { 
         if (this.toLoad_ < index) {
             this.toLoad_ += 5;
             var offset = 0;

             $http({
                 method: 'GET',
                 datatype: 'json',
                 url: '{my-api-call}',
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 cache: false,
                 params: {
                     param: query,
                     page: offset
                 }
              }).then(angular.bind(this, function (obj) {
                 this.items = this.items.concat(obj.data.SearchResults);
                 this.numLoaded_ = this.toLoad_;
                 this.offset++;
                 $scope.searchResults = obj.data.SearchResults;
              }));
         } 
     }
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a working sample to look at?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/e32qVQ4ECZBleWq2Gb2O?p=preview  In this example please remove few items from items.json file, then you see the empty rows.

Comment: did you find a way to solve it ? Im in the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it like this:

```
       $scope.infiniteBrands = {
            numLoaded_: 0,
            toLoad_: 0,
            items: [],
            page: -1,
            hasMoreItems: true,
            perPage: 7,
            //REQUIRED.
            getItemAtIndex: function(index) {
              if (index > this.numLoaded_) {
                this.fetchMoreItems_(index);
                return null;
              }
              return this.items[index];
            },
            //REQUIRED
            getLength: function() {
              return this.numLoaded_ + 1;
            },
            fetchMoreItems_: function(index) {
              if ( this.hasMoreItems && (this.toLoad_ < index)) {
                this.page++;
                this.toLoad_ += this.perPage;
                brandsFactory.getBrands(this.perPage, this.page)
                .then(angular.bind(this, function (data) {
                  this.items = this.items.concat(data);
                  if(data.length < this.perPage){
                    this.numLoaded_ = this.toLoad_ - (this.perPage - data.length) -1;
                    this.hasMoreItems = false;
                  }else{
                    this.numLoaded_ = this.toLoad_;                    
                  }

                }))
                .catch(function(errorResponse){
                  console.log('Error in brands controller, status : ', errorResponse.status);
                });
              }
            }
          };
```

As you can see the lines that prevents the empty rows are:

```
                  if(data.length < this.perPage){
                    this.numLoaded_ = this.toLoad_ - (this.perPage - data.length) -1;
                    this.hasMoreItems = false;
                  }else{
                    this.numLoaded_ = this.toLoad_;                    
                  }
```

where this.perPage are the number of items I want to ask per page but if the server returns me a lower number, because there are no more, I need to substract those from the this.numLoaded_ variable.

Its late but I hope it helps to anyone who had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your API call has reached the lastPage.

```
fetchMoreItems_: function (index) {
                if ((this.toLoad_ < index) && !this.lastPage) {
                    this.toLoad_ += this.size;
                    newsActions.getNews(this.page++, this.size).then(angular.bind(this, function (newsData) {
                        this.items = this.items.concat(newsData.content);
                        this.numLoaded_ = this.toLoad_ >= newsData.totalElements ? newsData.totalElements : this.toLoad_  ;
                        this.lastPage = newsData.last;
                    }));
                }
            }
```

Then use it in getLength function:

```
getLength: function () {
              if(this.lastPage){
                return this.numLoaded_
              }
              return this.numLoaded_ + 2;
            },
```